# Unable to read shapefiles with st_read() in R

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, r-sf

I am trying to read a shapefile

```
library(sf)
wards <- read_sf("Shape_files/benguluru_ward_boundaries_reprojected.shp")
```

and I am getting this error

```
Error in CPL_get_z_range(obj, 3) : z error - expecting three columns;
```

I googled it and it seems it has to do with z-dimension but I couldn't find a solution. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
This is what I am getting when I load the `sf` package

```
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

you can get the files [here](https://github.com/ashokpamidi/rough)

Edit2: I was able to solve this by running `extract z values` as mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43915/dropping-z-value-from-geometry-and-transfering-it-to-new-field/71597)  and there dropping it while exporting the layer. I am able to read that new layer without any issues.

Comment: Share your data so that others can see the problem for themselves.

Comment: Uploaded the files. I should have done it earlier.

Comment: Works for me. What version of `sf` are you on?

Comment: here it is
`> packageVersion("sf")
[1] ‘1.0.9’`

Comment: You should m also show the output from `library(sf)` so we can check the gdal and geos etc version numbers. Giving your operating system details as well helps. Works for me with R 4.1.1 sf 1.0.9 "Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE" on Linux. Please add this system info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround to this problem first by reading the layer using `terra` and then transforming the SpatVect to a sf object.

```
libary(terra)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
    
df <- terra::vect(path_to_shp) %>% st_as_sf()
```